# Select multiple rows from DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal-7

I have the array with some IDs(all are unique). I want to select data from database for every id in array. I try this code, but its not working, where is my mistake ?

```
$array = ....;
foreach ($array as $key => $id) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Are you using `$rows` somewhere? Also note that [`mysql_*` is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: no errors, white screen when var_dump(krumo) $rows

Comment: Try the example [from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). I.e. check if `empty($result)` and the output of `mysql_error()`.

Comment: hm...whe i using db_select all works fine. thanks)

Comment: I would not recommend mixing drupals `db_select()` and `mysql_*`. Your problem is still not clear for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$array = ......;
$id = implode(",", $array);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` where id IN($id)");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $user_id=$row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I want to propose another solution, try it :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE 1=1 ";

if(count($array){
    $query .= " AND (";
    foreach ($array as $key => $id) {
        $query .= ' OR id ='.$id;
    }
    $query .= ")";
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

and I hope this help you.

Comment: Variables in double quotes will be [expanded](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). that is not the issue.

Comment: @andy: I change the post.